# VMware in one instance multiple server

Tags: virtualization

I have one questions, in my office we have 8 blade servers DELL PowerEdge M630 in one chassis. Now I want create one instance with 8 blade server. Is it possible to create one instance of 8 Blade server ? second I want to install NVIDIA graphic card with one BL server and use the same card for graphic design.
Here is confusion is should I start VMware Esxi with BL no.1 and configure BL-1 to BL-8. or should I install VMWARE ESXI on all BL servers.

Kindly suggest how I configure 1 instance with 8 BL servers.

Thanks and regards,

Anand M.

Comment: Start by getting a professional in

Answer (score 1):

ESXi is a hypervisor, it does the heavy lifting in virtualization and allows virtual machines to use the underlying hardware of the machine it is installed on. This means it needs to be installed on every machine you want to run as a hypervisor.

If I understand you correctly, you want to manage all of the ESXi hosts from a central location. This is possible with the management software vCenter server which does things like high availability, failover, etc. With vCenter, you don't have to select which VM you want to put on which host, it just spreads them out for you.

If you don't want to pay for the licensing, you could just install open stack on the machines. It is a linux based virtualization with an open source management software. Ubuntu Server for example has a build in installer for it.

Comment: HI,

Thank you for your reply,
No,  My question is I have 8 blade servers with blade chassis, Can we make 8 blade server as 1 huge server 1:8. This will act as 1 server but actually 8 BL in installed in chassis. I mean to say 8 blade server club together, idea behind is I will install MAYA 2016 Graphic software and my all users will access remotely,   
please reply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnandM I see. This is not possible.

Comment: What could be best solution ?
Any option other than vCenter.

Comment: Don't know how maya works, but it can probably utilize a rendering farm, so render on multiple machines at once.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible is you don't pay for the premium version of esxi, with the extra management software.
But.
When you just want to use it for maya rendering, there's software you can use. 
It is called Backburner, and lets you install it on multiple computers, to let them work together in rendering. You can find more info on this over here: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-788EB610-5A7E-41C4-BD0C-1099FB9E72AF-htm.html